# Copy xml + Add root node and remove some parent node in the middle

Tags: xml, xslt

As Martin asked ([Copy xml + remove some positional nodes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33062933/copy-xml-remove-some-positional-nodes/33063178?noredirect=1#comment53971714_33063178)), I created a new question for my problem.

The thing is. I have in input the output from the previous question.
The thing is, i need to add another Root node. And inside the xml i need to remove the OtherDoc node. In the target they expect only the inner node.

Input

```
<ns0:parentnode xmlns:ns0="http://schemas.microsoft.com/namespace1" xmlns:s0="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003/aggschema">
   <ns0:childNode attribute1="test" attribute2="test">
      <levelA xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/namespace2"/>
   </ns0:childNode>
   <ns0:childNode2 Name="childNode2">
      <levelA xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/namespace3"/>
   </ns0:childNode2>
   <ns0:ChildNode3 Name="ChildNode3" id="2015-10-08-12.07.37.218960">
      <ns0:levelA Name="levelA">
         <ns0:data Name="Data" id="123456" type="A"/>
         <ns0:data Name="Data" id="654321" type="B"/>
         <ns0:levelAA id="910038265">
            <ns0:repeatingItem id="910568755">
               <ns0:comm Name="Communication" id="910041726" numberOfDocuments="3">
                  <ns0:group Name="Group" id="12">
                     <ns0:doc xmlns:s7="http://Schemas.RepeatingItemMessageInformation" id="123" archived="0"/>
                     <ns0:doc xmlns:s7="http://Schemas.RepeatingItemMessageInformation" id="321" archived="0"/>
                  </ns0:group>
               </ns0:comm>
            </ns0:repeatingItem>
         </ns0:levelAA>
         <ns0:doc id="123">
            <ns0:externalDoc content="base64string"/>
         </ns0:doc>
         <ns0:doc id="321">
            <ns0:externalDoc content="base64string"/>
         </ns0:doc>
      </ns0:levelA>
   </ns0:ChildNode3>
</ns0:parentnode>
```

Output

```
<ns0:First xmlns:ns0="http://schemas.microsoft.com/namespace1">
    <ns0:parentnode xmlns:ns0="http://schemas.microsoft.com/namespace1" xmlns:s0="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003/aggschema">
       <ns0:childNode attribute1="test" attribute2="test">
          <levelA xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/namespace2"/>
       </ns0:childNode>
       <ns0:childNode2 Name="childNode2">
          <levelA xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/namespace3"/>
       </ns0:childNode2>
       <ns0:ChildNode3 Name="ChildNode3" id="2015-10-08-12.07.37.218960">
          <ns0:levelA Name="levelA">
             <ns0:data Name="Data" id="123456" type="A"/>
             <ns0:data Name="Data" id="654321" type="B"/>
             <ns0:levelAA id="910038265">
                <ns0:repeatingItem id="910568755">
                   <ns0:comm Name="Communication" id="910041726" numberOfDocuments="3">
                      <ns0:group Name="Group" id="12">
                         <ns0:doc xmlns:s7="http://Schemas.RepeatingItemMessageInformation" id="123" archived="0"/>
                         <ns0:doc xmlns:s7="http://Schemas.RepeatingItemMessageInformation" id="321" archived="0"/>
                      </ns0:group>
                   </ns0:comm>
                </ns0:repeatingItem>
             </ns0:levelAA>
             <ns0:externalDoc content="base64string"/>
             <ns0:externalDoc content="base64string"/>
          </ns0:levelA>
       </ns0:ChildNode3>
    </ns0:parentnode>
</ns0:First>
```

So adding the rootnamespace is not a problem. I also can change the namespaces. Because also the source & target namespace are different.
The only thing i need is the OtherDoc removed. Without loosing the functionality to copy the full message. Because their is a lot more then this example xml

XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
                xmlns:var="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003/var"
                exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl var s0 " version="1.0"
                xmlns:ns0="http://schemas.microsoft.com/namespace1"
                xmlns:s0="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003/aggschema"
                xmlns:s7="http://Schemas.RepeatingItemMessageInformation"
                xmlns:ns1="http://schemas.microsoft.com/namespace2">

<xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" method="xml" version="1.0" indent="yes">     

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="/ns0:parentnode" />
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="/ns0:parentnode">
    <ns1:First>
      <ns1:parentnode>
        <xsl:for-each select="ns0:ChildNode3">
        <ns1:ChildNode3>
            <xsl:copy-of select="./@*" />
            <xsl:apply-templates select="./*" />
        </ns1:ChildNode3>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </ns1:parentnode>
    </ns0:First>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="ns0:*">
    <xsl:element name="ns1:{local-name()}">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
  </xsl:template>  

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to remove the `doc` node, but still output the children (in a different namespace), you just need to add another template to explicitly match the `doc`, which will just continue on by processing its children, but not output the node itself.

Add this template to your XSLT

```
 <xsl:template match="ns0:doc[ns0:externalDoc]">
     <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
 </xsl:template>
```

This will only match `doc` elements with a child `externalDoc`.

Alternately, you can match only `doc` elements within the `LevelA` element. You could also try this, in this case:

```
 <xsl:template match="ns0:levelA/ns0:doc">
     <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
 </xsl:template>
```

Comment: I edited the question. Some little problem. In my real example the ns0:doc is under the "group" and "levelA" node. So i can't use this template otherwise he will not copy everything from the one under "group"

Comment: In your question you say you "need to remove the OtherDoc node", but your XML no longer contains an "OtherDoc" node. If you actually want to remove the "doc" node, but change "OtherDoc" to "doc" in the template in the answer. Thanks!

Comment: In input i have "ns0:levelAA/ns0:doc", but you also have "ns0:group/ns0:doc". The one under "ns0:group" is OK. The one from "ns0:levelAA/ns0:doc/ns0:externalDoc" should be "ns0:levelAA/ns0:externalDoc"

Comment: I see now! I've amended my answer to show how this may be done.